# Can I take 3 bags of total 100 lb in Emirates?

Tags: luggage, international-travel, airlines, emirates

I have an emirates flight booked from US to India. The baggage policy on their site mentioned:
2*50lb weight

It says 2 but can we take extra bag if the total weight of 3 bags is still less than 100 lb? Or its just 2 bags at maximum in checkin?

Comment: Usually they'll ding you for an extra bag, regardless of weight, especially in economy. If you care about the money, try to put one bag inside another or possibly carry it on.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/95847/will-emirates-accept-one-25kg-bag-instead-of-two-23kg-bags

Answer (score 25, accepted):

On Emirates flights to or from the USA, [checked baggage is by piece](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/baggage/checked-baggage.aspx), not by total weight as is offered in most of the rest of the world. Here you can check two bags, each of which weighs up to 23 kg (50 lb). The total weight of all bags is not considered.

If you want to check a third item, it must also weigh no more than 23kg (50 lb), and a [$200 USD charge applies](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/baggage/purchase-additional-baggage-allowance.aspx).